Laravel 11 validation requiring a single item in an array has to be one of the following
I am using form request validation and allow for vehicles to be created in the form. Each vehicle has a ref which can be A, B, C, or D. However, in each form request there must always be a single ref: "A". There can be any amount of the others.
I am not in control of the form. The requests come through an API.
My rules array currently contains:
'form.vehicles' => 'required',
'form.vehicles.*.ref' => 'required|in:A,B,C,D

Currently I am using the following code:
if (! in_array('A', $this->input('form.vehicles.*.ref'))) {
  throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(['MessageString' => 'Vehicle ref A is required'], 422));

This however means the messageBag is unable to be sent in the response for other validation issues.

How are you doing this validation? Is it a FormRequest, a Manual Validator, or something else? You should be able to add messages to the Error MessageBage instead of throwing an Exception, but it depends on your approach, which you didn't show here. Alternatively, you might be able to define a Custom Rule that checks form.vehicles for an entry that contains ref: 'A', and use it like 'form.vehicles' => ['required', new RefCheckRule()], or similar.

Thanks for the comment. This is being done with FormRequest.
I used your suggestion of creating a custom rule implementing ValidationRule
`$requiredVehicle = collect($value)->first(function ($vehicle) {
return $vehicle['ref'] === 'A';
});
if ($requiredVehicle === null) {
$fail('Vehicle A is required');
}`
I'm unable to create an answer but this comment works for me

Excellent! Glad to hear you got it working  You should be able to post an answer below (to my knowledge, there isn't any restriction on Stackoverflow on posting a self-answer, even at 1 Reputation), but ultimately, it's more important for you to get your code working. Cheers!

I used Tim Lewis's suggestion of creating a custom rule implementing ValidationRule:
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule;

class VehicleA implements ValidationRule
{
    /**
     * Run the validation rule.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(string): \Illuminate\Translation\PotentiallyTranslatedString  $fail
     */
    public function validate(string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail): void
    {
        $requiredVehicle = collect($value)->first(function ($vehicle) { 
            return $vehicle['ref'] === 'A';
        });  

        if ($requiredVehicle === null) { 
            $fail('Vehicle A is required'); 
        }
    }

Inside my form request:
'form.vehicles' => [
    'required',
    new VehicleA,
],

